# Change Formatting of \subsubsection just once?

Tags: sectioning, mdframed, bold

For a part in a subsection of my book I use a `\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]`, which is a grey box aroound a part of my text. I would like the subsubsection title in the box, and only in the box, to be in bold fonts just this one time, to highlight it and set it off from the rest of the text.

This:

```
\subsubsection{\textbf{European Law}}
```

Does lead to a bold font for the text, but not for the numbering. Is there any option or aay to change the numbering to bold for this instance, too?

Comment: In standard `book`, both the number and the (subsub)section title are bold by default -- if this is not the case, there's a change or you're using a different class than `book`. -- Do you really want to use the `\subsubsection` title in the box?

Comment: There must be a misunderstanding; I use subsubsection in several other instances, it is by default not in bold font. But i need it for this one instance, in the mdframe, in bold. I.e. I know how to change subsubsection for all instances, but am wondering how to change it just once.

Comment: Please provide a document to work with, anything else is guessing around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways -- with `mdframed` and `tcolorbox` -- the numbers are bold, as well as the title by default (in `book`)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foo}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]
\subsubsection{Foo}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=lightgray,enhanced,sharp corners,boxrule=0pt]
\subsubsection{Foo}
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]